# Xamarin --- playing an Android alarm for a short duration

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

So I have a Xamarin Android app, where the user inputs values into a textbox. In practicality they barcode scan SKU's. If the SKU is found in a local file then a notification sound plays (i.e. - RingtoneType.Notification). This works fine. It just plays the tone a single time.

But if the SKU isn't found in the local file I want to play a different tone. I've tried both the RingtoneType.Alarm and RingtoneType.Ringtone enum values and these play continuously.

What is a simple method I can employ to play a different tone a single time that differs from the RingtoneType.Notification sound?

I've tried to invoke the Stop() method, but I think since the context is lost, the tone still continuously plays regardless.

```
        public void playSuccess(Context context)
        {
            soundUri = RingtoneManager.GetDefaultUri(RingtoneType.Notification);
            r = RingtoneManager.GetRingtone(context, soundUri);
            r.Play();
        }

        public void playFailure(Context context)
        {
            soundUri = RingtoneManager.GetDefaultUri(RingtoneType.Alarm);
            r = RingtoneManager.GetRingtone(context, soundUri);
            r.Play();            
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, I think you can use Timer to time.

```
 public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
{

    private TextView textview;
    private Button btn;
    private Button btn2;
    Ringtone r;
    private Timer timer;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
        textview = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView1);
        btn = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button1);
        btn2 = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button2);
        btn.Click += delegate
          {                 
             playSuccess(ApplicationContext);               
          };
        btn2.Click += delegate
          {
              playFailure(ApplicationContext);
          };
        timer = new Timer(5000);
        timer.Enabled = true;


    }

    private void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        r.Stop();
        timer.Stop();
    }

    private void playSuccess(Context context)
    {
       Uri soundUri = RingtoneManager.GetDefaultUri(RingtoneType.Notification);
       r = RingtoneManager.GetRingtone(context, soundUri);
        r.Play();
    }

    private void playFailure(Context context)
    {

        Uri soundUri = RingtoneManager.GetDefaultUri(RingtoneType.Alarm);
         r = RingtoneManager.GetRingtone(context, soundUri);         
        r.Play();
        timer.Start();
        timer.Elapsed += Timer_Elapsed;

    }
}

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView android:id="@+id/textView1" 
          android:layout_width="match_parent" 
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="cherry"  />

<Button android:id="@+id/button1" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Play audio"/>

<Button android:id="@+id/button2" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Play another audio"/>
```

As my code, I set 5 second for RingtoneType.Alarm.

Comment: That was the ticket! I forgot about something as simple as the Timer class. Was first thinking about a thread sleep scenario, but figured that Android and the .NET aspects of things wouldn't play nicely. That worked perfectly and fixed my annoying method. Thanks for the help!